# Jumbled words solver using LSTM networks

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement an LSTM network to detect the correct order of jumbled words in a sentence. How to I label the dataset? My dataset consists of sentences with maximum 6 words. What should be the representation of my output layer?

For example, if my sentence is 'is this neural a network'
ordering is 2,1,4,3,5 -> this is a neural network

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any NLP task such as this you should be using word embeddings, e.g. Word2Vec. Each word will be represented as a vector. Your input will be a matrix of these vectors in the original, incorrect order. Your output will be a matrix of these vectors in the correct order. Below, I've included a link to a Fast.ai course that further discusses word embeddings.

https://course.fast.ai/lessons/lesson6.html

*Note that based on the problem formulation, I'm assuming your RNN is capable of handling input / output sentence pairs. If that's not the case or you run into problems along those lines, leave a comment and I can give you some more ideas.